# conserve stack space when using virtual function calls

Tags: c++, embedded, microcontroller

I'm currently developing in C++ for an STM32 µC. Basically, I wanted to add a layer of abstraction to i²c in order to have virtual i²c buses that are actually behind a multiplexer on the physical i²c bus.

We already had a driver that would combine the driver and multiplexer logic, with an obvious lack in the OOP department there...
So I added a level of indirection to I²C accesses and a virtual bus implementation to decouple driver from multiplexer logic and hide global knowledge:

```
Device -> Virtual I²C -> I²C Multiplexer -> Abstracted I²C -> Low-Level I²C
```

Now my problem is basically, that each of the interfaces has to define a transmit function

```
virtual
transmit(const uint8_t address,
         uint8_t *tx,
         size_t lentx,
         const uint8_t *rx,
         const size_t lenrx,
         const size_t timeout
         );
```

Which just passes some arguments through. Usually:

```
virtual
transmit(...) {

    this->driver->transmit(this->address, ...);

}
```

However, as it turns out, each virtual function call adds a whopping 40 bytes to my stack requirements, because they:

1. get the arguments on the stack
2. allocate stack for their function call
3. copy the inputs to the right place on the newly allocated part of the stack
4. execute the function call
5. copy the outputs back to the right place on the stack for incoming arguments

Now, we only recently switched to using C++, so I'm still not that knowledgeable about the fine-tunings for embedded system development with that. However, it seems odd to me that already three levels of indirection would basically have me run out of stack space...
For instance, I'm losing 164 bytes this way traversing the virtual calls alone: Device to Virtual Bus, Virtual Bus to I²C Multiplexer, I²C Multiplexer to Abstracted I²C, where the real call takes place.

The desired solution is kind of obvious. The virtual function call should obviously only allocate as much space at it needs for additional variables that it needs to pass and reorder the arguments:

```
Incoming: tx*, len, rx*, len, to
Allocate: tx*, len, rx*, len, to, ___
Reorder : ___, tx*, len, rx*, len, to
Add args: sla, tx*, len, rx*, len, to
     ---------- Call ----------
Reorder : tx*, len, rx*, len, to, ___
Dealloc : tx*, len, rx*, len, to
Output  : tx*, len, rx*, len, to
```

So the real question is: can I force GCC to notice this pass-through-style behavior and force it to conserve as much stack space as possible?
I'm really at a loss here, seeing as I only use PODs to begin with...

Comment: Hmya, it is rather questionable that tool vendors that promote a C++ compiler on such limited hardware are ever doing their customers a favor.  It is useful for a programmer though, a bit like learning the ropes by falling off the horse many times, you *do* get to understand the machine better.  And no, there's no magic cure for the cost of dynamic dispatch.  You do get learn and pick yourself up from the dust by analyzing the *true* need for virtual functions.  In the Device -> ... -> Low-Level I²C chain, are you *ever* truly going to substitute *all* of them?

Comment: The thing is, the cost is not in having virtual function calls. The cost is simply by calling three functions that pass their arguments through resp. add one argument.
As far as substitution goes, I'm already substituting the Hardware I²C for Virtual I²C using the same driver. So now it's only a matter of time, when we might need a second driver going through a multiplexer :-/
I would have the same cost using regular functions and structs with function pointers at run time.

Comment: Does applying optimisation have any effect (`-O3`)?  Without optimisation the compiler is more or less obliged to explicitly code that which might otherwise be trivially optimised away - if only to make debugging more straightforward.

Comment: @HansPassant: Some STM32 parts are "limited", some are not.

Comment: It's a high-density STM32F4, optimization does not have any impact on this... 40 to 48 bytes on the stack per function call... :(

Comment: Consider using templates instead of virtual methods.  Then you'd switch between, for example, `EEPROM<I2CMultiplexer>` and `EEPROM<I2CBus>` at compile time.  With `inline` methods and full optimization, your compiler can hopefully get rid of some of the nested function calls.

Comment: japreiss, that's actually a cool idea. Unfortunately, I have kind of run out of time to try this approach. However, I would think that this might yield the snappiest code with clear-cut policies. Nice ;)

Answer (score 2):

Although you cannot convince gcc to change the layout of the stack automatically, you can certainly do it manually by defining a single `struct` on which you set the parameters, and passing around a shared pointer to that `struct`.

Here is how you can do it:

```
struct TxRxParams {
    uint8_t *tx;
    size_t lentx;
    const uint8_t *rx;
    const size_t lenrx;
};
```

Now you can allocate `TxRxParams` once, and pass a pointer to it to various functions, virtual or not, to save stack space.

Comment: That's a nice idea. I'll try that and see how much it cuts down cost. Because these would still need to be created on the stack in user functions, I fear I'd only save on the outer-most level :-/

Comment: OK, that was a nice answer indeed. Passthrough cost is now only 8 bytes (for two arguments, TxRxParams* and const size_t). It might have seemed obvious to you, but I didn't see that before ;)